# Is there a measurable injective function from the plane to a line?

Tags: measure-theory

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}$ be a measurable function. Is it possible that $f$ is injective? It is easy to prove that there is no such continuous function using connectedness, and it is straightforward to use the axiom of choice to construct an injection $\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}$, but I see no way to prove or disprove the existence of such a measurable function.

Comment: Let $\mathbb P$ be the irrational numbers. Maybe you can somehow define very nice injections (e.g. homeomorphisms) $\mathbb P\times\mathbb P\to\mathbb P\to\mathbb P\cap(0,1)$ and then extend it somehow to $\mathbb R\times\mathbb R$?

Comment: Anyway, I'm sure you don't need the axiom of choice to get a bijection between $\mathbb R\times\mathbb R$ and $\mathbb R$, and any function you can define without using the axiom of choice is likely to be measurable.

Comment: Without the axiom of choice, you can define a continuous surjection $g:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R^2$ and then a (necessarily injective) function $f:\mathbb R^2\to\mathbb R$ such that $g(f(x,y))=(x,y)$.

Comment: To make @bof's idea a proof one could try https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kuratowski_and_Ryll-Nardzewski_measurable_selection_theorem

Comment: @Jochen If the continuous surjection $g:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R^2$ is constructed so that $\{t\in\mathbb R:g(t)=(x.y)\}$ is finite for each point $(x,y)\in\mathbb R^2$, then we can simply define $f(x,y)=\min\{t\in\mathbb R:g(t)=(x,y)\}$, and then $\{(x,y)\in\mathbb R^2:f(x,y)\lt c\}=\{g(t):t\lt c\}$ is an $\text F_\sigma$ set.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are diffeomorphisms $\Bbb R\to(0,1)$, so it's enough to have a Borel injection $(0,1)^2\to (0,1)$. Given $x\ge0$, define $2_j(x)=\lfloor 2^jx\rfloor -2\lfloor 2^{j-1}x\rfloor$. This is the $(-j)$-th binary digit of $x$; namely $\{2_j(x)\}_{j\in\Bbb Z}$ is the sequence in $\{0,1\}$ such that $x=\sum_{j\in\Bbb Z}2^{-j}2_j(x)$ and $\liminf_{n\to\infty}2_n(x)\ne1$.

Now, we can easily define a Borel injection $G:(0,1)^2\to(0,1)$ $$G(x,y)=\sum_{j=0}^\infty 2^{-2j}2_j(x)+\sum_{j=0}^\infty 2^{-2j-1}2_j(y)$$

This is Borel because it's limit of Borel functions. Moreover, notice that the sequence $$a_j=\begin{cases}2_{j/2}(x)&\text{if }j\text{ even}\\ 2_{(j-1)/2}(y)&\text{if }j\text{ odd}\end{cases}$$

is a sequence in $\{0,1\}$ such that $\liminf_{n\to\infty}a_n\ne 1$ and $\sum_{j\in\Bbb Z}a_j2^{-j}=G(x,y)$. Therefore $a_j=2_j(G(x,y))$. This provides the explicit section $$(x,y)=\left(\sum_{j=0}^\infty 2^{-j}2_{2j}(G(x,y)), \sum_{j=0}^\infty 2^{-j}2_{2j+1}(G(x,y))\right)$$

and therefore $G$ is injective.

**Added:** The function $G$ and Cantor-Bernstein can be used to devise a Borel bijection $(0,1)^2\to(0,1)$ with Borel inverse. The ingredients are:

1. Cantor-Bernstein in this formulation. Let $f:X\to Y$ and $g:Y\to X$ be injections; define $$CB(f,g)(x)=\begin{cases}f(x)&\text{if } x\in \bigcup_{n\ge 0} (g\circ f)^n[X\setminus g[Y]]\\ g^{-1}(x)&\text{if }x\in \bigcup_{n\ge 0}(g\circ f)^n\circ g[Y\setminus f[X]]\\ f(x)&\text{if } x\in \bigcap_{n\ge 0} (g\circ f)^n[X]\end{cases}.$$ $CB(f,g)$ is a bijection $X\to Y$ and its inverse is $CB(\tilde g,f)$, where $$\tilde g(y)=\begin{cases}f^{-1}(y)&\text{if }y\in \bigcap_{n\ge 0} (f\circ g)^n[Y]\\ g(y)&\text{if }y\notin \bigcap_{n\ge 0}(f\circ g)^n[Y]\end{cases}$$
2. From (1), the following "measurable" version of Cantor-Bernstein is apparent. Let $(X,\mathcal E)$ and $(Y,\mathcal F)$ be measurable spaces and let $f:X\to Y$, $g:Y\to X$ be measurable injections that send measurable sets to measurable sets (let's call such functions *mensural embeddings* for the time being). Then, $CB(f,g)$ is a measurable bijection with measurable inverse.
3. It's easy to prove that the following are equivalent: 1) $f:(X,\mathcal E)\to (Y,\mathcal F)$ is a mensural embedding; 2) $f$ is measurable, $\operatorname{im}f$ is measurable and there is a measurable function $g:Y\to X$ such that $g\circ f=id_X$, or $X=\emptyset$.

Now, let's specialize the discussion to $(X,\mathcal E)=((0,1)^2,\mathcal B(0,1)^2)$, $(Y,\mathcal F)=((0,1),\mathcal B(0,1))$ and $f=G$. I've already proved that $G$ is Borel with Borel left inverse, so by (3) I only need to prove that $\operatorname{im}G$ is Borel. This is easy because $$\operatorname{im}G=\left\{x\in (0,1)\,:\, 2_1(x)=0\land \liminf_{j\to\infty} \,2_{2j}(x)\ne 1\land \liminf_{j\to\infty}\,2_{2j+1}(x)\ne 1\right\}.$$
An obvious mensural embedding $u:(0,1)\to (0,1)^2$ is $u(x)=(x,1/2)$.